Problem when remapping caps lock to escape using xmodmap
I am using arch linux.I made some key modifications and one of them is caps lock to escape (this is why i used xmodmap instead of the setxkbmap one line swap escape) the problem is when adding "clear lock" to .Xmodmap for some reason special keys that are written using AltGr for example brackets (i am using a french keyboard) stop working.
the part where the keys are swapped :
    clear lock
    
    keycode 66 = Escape NoSymbol Escape
    
    keycode 9 = Caps_Lock NoSymbol Caps_Lock
    
    add lock = Caps_Lock

the contents of 00-keyboard.conf
Section "Input Class"
    Identifier "system-keyboard"
    MatchIsKeyboard "on"
    Option "XkbLayout" "fr,ara"
    Option "XkbModel" "pc102"
    Option "XkbVariant" "azerty,azerty"
  Option "XkbOptions" "grp:win_space_toggle,caps:escape"
EndSection

and my xinitrc has xmodmap.
is there a solution to this or can you use both setxkbmap (for swapping caps:escape) and xmodmap(for other changes) at the same time(is there a way to disable setxkbmap setting all changes to default and only use the option specified)
